# C++/Lua RPG tut?

Tags: c++, scripting, lua

Looking for a tut on how to go about making a RPG scripting engine in c++ using lua.

Comment: as in rocket propelled grenade or role play game or ...? ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get your hands on a copy of "Lua Programming Gems".

There is a whole part (chapters 20 through 23) dedicated to game programming. It's perhaps not tailored exactly to your needs, but the whole book is a gem in my bookshelf. Love it and it's in the top ten of those I reach for most frequently. And yes, even if you want specifically game programming, the other chapters very likely also have something in them for you ...

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using [Luabind](http://www.rasterbar.com/products/luabind.html), as their page says:

> It has the ability to expose functions and classes, written in C++, to Lua. It will also supply the functionality to define classes in lua and let them derive from other lua classes or C++ classes.

Then all your Lua code can just call the methods you wrote in C++.